# Calling functions from other components in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I call functions from other components in react-native ?

I have this custom component which renders another component defined somewhere else and a image button. When tapping the image I want to call a function from the other component. When executing the example below I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating this.otherComponent.doSomething')`

```
export default class MainComponent extends Component {

  _onPressButton() {
    this.otherComponent.doSomething();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TagContainer style={styles.flow_container} ref={(instance) => this.otherComponent = instance}>
        </TagContainer>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}><Image source={require('./img/ic_add.png')} style={styles.add_tags_button_view} /></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and

```
export default class OtherComponent extends Component {

    addTag() {
        this.state.tags = this.state.tags.push("plm");
        console.log('success..');
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this be: this.refs.otherComponent.addTag(); ?
and <TagContainer  ref="otherComponent"></TagContainer>

Comment: https://reactnatve.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/refs-to-components/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direct communication between components is not recommended, because it breaks encapsulation. It's a good practice to send a prop to the component and let it handles the change inside the method `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
   
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: ++this.state.value });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>click me</a>
        <Child value={this.state.value}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { value: 0 };
  }
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({ value: nextProps.value });
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: Great answer, could you extend on `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`. It doesn't seem to be needed?

Comment: @Mick yes, in this case, it is necessary in order to make `this` work in the function `handleClick`. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I believe this is a different solution because in the OPs question the other component owns the state, not the main component.

Comment: You saved my life. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 12):

### Calling Remote Methods in Functional Components

To do this with functional components, you must do this:

**Parent**

1. Give the child component a reference in the parent using `useRef()`:

```js
const childRef = useRef()
// ...
return (
   <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
)
...
```

**Child**

1. Pass `ref` into the constructor:

```js
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  // ...
}
```

2. Import `useImperativeHandle` and `forwardRef` from `'react'`:

```js
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react'
```

3. Use `useImperativeHandle` to connect methods to the `ref` object.

These methods won't be internally available, so you may want to use them to call internal methods.

```js
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  //...
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // each key is connected to `ref` as a method name
    // they can execute code directly, or call a local method
    method1: () => { localMethod1() },
    method2: () => { console.log("Remote method 2 executed") }
  }))
  //...
  
  // These are local methods, they are not seen by `ref`,
  const localMethod1 = () => {
    console.log("Method 1 executed")
  }
  // ..
}
```

4. Export the child component using `forwardRef`:

```js
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  // ...
}
export default forwardRef(ChildComponent)
```

### Putting it all together

**Child Component**

```js
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native'


const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // methods connected to `ref`
    sayHi: () => { sayHi() }
  }))
  // internal method
  const sayHi = () => {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
  return (
    <View />
  );
}

export default forwardRef(ChildComponent)
```

**Parent Component**

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent';

const App = () => {
  const childRef = useRef()
  return (
    <View>
      <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          childRef.current.sayHi()
        }}
        title="Execute Child Method"
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

There is an interactive demo of this on Expo Snacks:
https://snack.expo.dev/@backupbrain/calling-functions-from-other-components

This explanation is modified from this [TutorialsPoint article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs-useimperativehandle-hook)

Comment: If you have errors calling the function from parent, declare an extra type for the functions like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69292925/4465464

Answer (score -5):

Need not have to define the function inside class . Here is an example

in the helpers.js

```
export async function getAccessKey(){
let accessToken =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
return accessToken;
}
```

in the calling class.

```
import { getAccessKey } from '../components/helpers';
...
//inside the method
      let  key = await getAccessKey();
```