# declare type with React.useImperativeHandle()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
function App(){
  const cntEl:any = React.useRef(null);  // I don't know what type should be here.
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(cntEl.current){ cuntEl.current.start() }
  }, []);
  return <Countdown ref={cntEl} />
}
const Countdown = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, ()=>({
    start() {
      alert('Start');
    }
  });
  return <div>Countdown</div>
});
```

I try to use a child method in a parent component using `ref` and `React.useImperativeHandle()`.

It works well.

but I am not satisfied because of `const cntEl:any`.

I believe there are many ways to avoid using `any` type I don't know.

I just need a type that could be replaced type `any`.

**Edited**

I can see `(property) React.MutableRefObject<null>.current: null` when I hover at `cntEl.current`

Comment: There is an example shows how to use useImperativeHandle in Typescript
https://youtu.be/akeb4SFWcJM

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I recommend you use type definitions more explicitly

For example, with React DT, you can define ref exotic component with `ForwardRefRenderFunction` instead of `FC`.

```
type CountdownProps = {}
    
type CountdownHandle = {
  start: () => void,
}
    
const Countdown: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<CountdownHandle, CountdownProps> = (
  props,
  forwardedRef,
) => {
  React.useImperativeHandle(forwardedRef, ()=>({
    start() {
      alert('Start');
    }
  });

  return <div>Countdown</div>;
}

export default React.forwardRef(Countdown);
```

and then use React utility `ElementRef`, TypeScript can infer exact ref type of your component

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  // this will be inferred as `CountdownHandle`
  type CountdownHandle = React.ElementRef<typeof Countdown>;

  const ref = React.useRef<CountdownHandle>(null); // assign null makes it compatible with elements.

  return (
    <Countdown ref={ref} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Worth noting that `RefForwardingComponent` has been deprecated and the type defs suggest using `ForwardRefRenderFunction` instead.

Comment: You may also simply declare it as `const Countdown = React.forwardRef(props: CountdownProps, ref: React.Ref<CountdownHandle>) => { ... })`

Comment: Remove React.FC from typescript. [pull](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177)

Comment: type CountdownHandle = React.ElementRef<typeof Countdown>;
changed to
type CountdownHandle = React.ElementRef<typeof ReactForwardRef>;
Otherwise, an error will be reported Property 'start' does not exist on type 'never'.ts

Answer (score 158):

The accepted answer is overcomplicated, you **just need to declare a `CountdownHandle` type**.

For me it'll go like this:

```js
// Countdown.tsx

export type CountdownHandle = {
  start: () => void;
};

type Props = {};

const Countdown = React.forwardRef<CountdownHandle, Props>((props, ref) => {
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // start() has type inferrence here
    start() {
      alert('Start');
    },
  }));

  return <div>Countdown</div>;
});
```

```
// The component uses the Countdown component

import Countdown, { CountdownHandle } from "./Countdown.tsx";

function App() {
  const countdownEl = React.useRef<CountdownHandle>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (countdownEl.current) {
      // start() has type inferrence here as well
      countdownEl.current.start();
    }
  }, []);

  return <Countdown ref={countdownEl} />;
}
```

Comment: This one is indeed easier to understand and works great! Thanks.

Comment: This one should be the right answer , easy to understand and it works !

Comment: Agreed, this is far simpler to understand, and I finally get it after about 18 months of trying hacks from various posts - wish I had found this one earlier. Time to refactor...

Comment: for clarity - "It’s a bit confusing because the ordering of the generic parameters (ref and then props) is the opposite of the ordering of the function parameters (props and then ref)."  https://www.carlrippon.com/react-forwardref-typescript/

Comment: What if `Component` is also generic? such as `interface Props<T> { name: T; }` and the Component maybe `function Component<T>(props: Props<T>)`

Comment: And if the Countdown component has to get the ref from `<div>Countdown</div>` ? It doesn't work because the type is not HTMLElement.

Comment: @AdrianGonzález Interesting, I never expect to use `useImperativeHandle` and forward the ref to the inside `div` at the same time, why would you want that? Maybe you can use something like this https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-forwardref/#3-useimperativehandle or any better idea is totally welcome!

Comment: Yes, it's something like that. Instead of managing everything through a single reference, it is possible to do it through different references, each of which will share different data and methods.